# I need to know gas price C# Nethereum

Tags: gas, gas-price, nethereum, c#

How can I get current gas price?
I want to calculate the gas fee per transaction. I need to multiply Gas Price by _estimatedGas. I looked at the Gas price on https://bscscan.com/ it's 5 Gwei. Can I get this value through the code?

```
        var _estimatedGas = new HexBigInteger(new BigInteger(35000));
        try
        {
            _estimatedGas = func.EstimateGasAsync(
                account.Address,
                new HexBigInteger(new BigInteger(_transactionValue)),
                new HexBigInteger(new BigInteger(_transactionValue)),
                inputParameters).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            taskManager.Logger($"_estimatedGas: {_estimatedGas} \n", 7);
            
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            taskManager.Logger($"Error can't get GAS amount {e.Message} \n \n", 7);
            return;
        }
        

        taskManager.Logger($"amountMin: {((BigInteger)amountMin-_estimatedGas)} _estimatedGas.Value: {_estimatedGas.Value} _transactionValue: {_transactionValue}. \n \n", 7);
        inputParameters[0] = new HexBigInteger((BigInteger)amountMin-_estimatedGas);
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems Nethereum doesn't have such function built-in. You'll have to get `gasPrice` from some API like [EthGasStation](https://docs.ethgasstation.info/gas-price)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue some time ago.

Before showing the code, keep in mind that:

```
Fee = GasPrice * Gas
```

The **GasPrice** is the same for all network parties. What changes per transaction is the amount of **Gas**.
E.g.: Deploying a smart contract will probably demand much more **Gas** than sending Ether to another wallet/account.

According to the current Nethereum version, you can use the following:

#### Estimating **Gas** for sending Ether:

```cs
Account senderAccount = new(privateKey);
Web3 web3 = new(senderAccount, "https://infura.your-provider-here.com");

await web3.Eth.GetEtherTransferService().EstimateGasAsync(destinationAddress, etherAmount);
```

#### Getting **GasPrice**:

```cs
Account senderAccount = new(privateKey);
Web3 web3 = new(senderAccount, "https://infura.your-provider-here.com");

await web3.Eth.GasPrice.SendRequestAsync();
```

Also, you should know that to make sure your transaction will be mined and processed you can, for example, increase the **Gas** or **GasPrice** in a percentage.